# What Checksum Algorithm used

Tags: crc, checksum

I have blocks 1 to 4 of an RFID card with 4-byte Hex data each. Block 5 contains some sort of 4-byte Hex data checksum which I would like to know how it was derived.

Please see the 3 sample data below:

(1)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 1B 1B |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 64 64 DA 9C |
| Block 4 | 1A DA A3 00 |
| Block 5 | C7 60 01 E9 |

(2)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 1B 1B |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 67 67 DA 9C |
| Block 4 | 1A DA A3 00 |
| Block 5 | DA 3D E6 E7 |

(3)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 1B 1B |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 6A 6D DA 9C |
| Block 4 | 1A DA A3 00 |
| Block 5 | 22 B7 DE 6F |

Please note that only changes in block 3 1st and 2nd column data resulted in the changes shown in block 5 data in each of the sample.

Could anyone figure out how the checksums were calculated?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As you assume it is a CRC have you checked that if block1-4 are identical you get the same block 5?

Comment: @Robert Many thanks for your response. Please note that if blocks 1-4 are identical, block 5 is the same. What other algorithm would you suggest that would result in 32 bits from 128 bit data?

Comment: Can you manipulate single Bytes in Block 3? Such as "65 64 DA 9C" "66 64 DA 9C" or "64 64 DA 9D" etc?

Comment: @ dieter reichl Many thanks for your response. The Bytes are generated by hardware (card writer) The only way I can manipulate the Bytes in  Block 3 is to rewrite the Bytes to the RFID card using another card writer, which I can readily do. Please note that a change to any of the Bytes in Blocks 1-4 requires a corresponding change to Block 5  Bytes as well.